Vampire film about a family whose teen daughter is targeted by a young-looking female vampire
I've been trying to recall the name of a vampire movie which must have been made in the 70s-90s. It seems to my mind that it could have been a British film. If anyone else has seen it, then I'm sure the scenes that still stand out in my mind some 30 years later will jog their memory and help me find this movie.
The first scene that really affected me was of the vampire sucking the girl's neck as she (the victim) walks hypnotized through some ruins near their home. The vampire is floating feet up in the air while hanging on to the girl's throat by her teeth.
The second scene was of the house maid; a chubby black woman being attacked by bats that swarm over her body while biting her and then I believe the bats are replaced by the vampire, who slashes the woman's throat with her hand.

A lot of vampire films are period pieces, set in the 19th century or earlier. Was this a period piece, or was it set around the time that it was made?

Could have been inspired by Le Fanu's classic "Carmilla," which is the archetypal teen-daughter-targeted-by-young-looking-female-vampire novel. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmilla lists 2 adaptations from the 70s and links to articles on a similar theme - might be worth a dig.

Was the any scenes with the garlic?

The 1933 film "The Vampire Bat" has a maid attacked by bats, but I think it's just bats for most of the film. Plus, it's black and white and clearly looks like an older film.

This is probably the Carmilla adaptation created for the Showtime "Nightmare Classics" television series. It aired in September of 1989. It stars Ione Skye and Meg Tilly.
The whole thing is on YouTube - the first scene you mention is about 33 minutes in and the second one is at about 22 minutes.
